# Teradata snap date view

Tags: date, view, teradata, snapshot

I have a base teradata table. It has 2 dates - from_date and to_date
Example
Base Table: Student_Address 
(Blank To_date indicates current date, latest record)

```
Student Address From_date To_date
A        A1      1/1/2015  6/2/2015
A        A2      6/3/2015     ?
```

Required view: Student_Address_View
Student  Address snap_date

when the user specifies

```
select * from Student_Address where snap_date = '2015-02-10',
```

it should give first record

when the user specifies

```
select * from Student_Address where snap_date = '2017-02-10',
```

it should give second record

Comment: you probably want something like `where date '2015-02-10' between From_date and coalesce(To_date, current_date)`

Comment: Both `snap_date` are same in your example. Kindly clarify your example.